# ArrayStoreException while creating Morphia Datastore

Tags: java, mongodb, datastore, morphia, arraystoreexception

I'm trying to create a MongoDB database using Morphia, however when I create the Morphia Datastore, I get the following error:

```
[18:33:13 WARN]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: dev.morphia.mapping.codec.PrimitiveCodecRegistry
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.<init>(Mapper.java:96)
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//dev.morphia.DatastoreImpl.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:70)
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//dev.morphia.Morphia.createDatastore(Morphia.java:49)
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//dev.morphia.Morphia.createDatastore(Morphia.java:60)
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//io.github.vyketype.terranova.database.Database.init(Database.java:49)
[18:33:13 WARN]:        at TerraNova-1.0-ALPHA-all.jar//io.github.vyketype.terranova.TerraNova.onEnable(TerraNova.java:34)
and the rest of the stack trace leading to the Java library stuff...
```

I've researched the cause of this exception and I understood that this is an issue concerning arrays, but I'm not using any arrays. This error is happening when I'm creating the Datastore. Here is some of my code.

```java
private MongoClient client;
private Datastore datastore;

public void init() {
    String confString = Objects.requireNonNull(instance.getConfig().getString("database"));
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(confString);
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
            .build();
    client = MongoClients.create(settings);
    datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(client, "terranova-test");
    datastore.ensureIndexes();
    datastore.getMapper().map(User.class);
}
```

All of this code is in a `Database` class. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why, in particular, I am getting an `ArrayStoreException`. This error has been bugging me for quite some time now, all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I saw this happen was due to having conflicting versions of either Morphia or the driver.  I'd start looking there.